# How to use the "In progress" correctly

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it right if I say "I'm working on multiple projects in progress" to describe that these projects are not finished ?

Answer (score 2):

It's acceptable to say,

> I'm working on multiple projects in progress.

It's somewhat redundant, though, because `I'm working` implies that they're in progress. It might be simpler to say,

> I've multiple projects in progress.

Comment: Or *I'm working on multiple projects.*